# Use of polar coordinate delta function in line interation

Tags: polar-coordinates, dirac-delta, surface-integrals, line-integrals

Suppose constant value,I is defined as,
\begin{align}
 I=\int_{circle}f(r,\theta)\ dl
\end{align}
where equation of the circle is defined as $r=\cos(\theta-\frac{\pi}{4})$ (see plot below). Now in an article author claims that I can be written in this way also,
\begin{align}
I=\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta \int_{0}^{\infty}dr \ f(r,\theta) \  \delta[r-\cos(\theta-\frac{\pi}{4})]
\end{align}
$\ \ $Here, line integration is replaced by surface integration by introducing delta factor.

$\ \ $But, in plane polar coordinate surface element factor is $\ \ ``r\ dr\ d\theta" \ \ $. Where is that $\ \ ``r"\ \ $ factor? Is that some how taken care inside delta factor?

[image: polar plot of the circle]

Comment: The second way to write $I$ is particularly ugly. The curve defined by $r = a \cos(\theta - \frac{\pi}{4})$ is a circle centered at $(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{2}},\frac{a}{2\sqrt{2}})$ with radius $\frac{a}{2}$. If $f(r, \theta)$ is defined in polar coordinates, one expects that it is defined when $r \ge 0$. But on the circle, it means that $\theta \in [\frac{-\pi}{4},\frac{3 \pi}{4}]$. These should at least be the bounds of $\theta$ in the integral. Also the $*$ symbol looks like a convolution. The meaning of the expression is unclear, so it is a bad way to write things.